# How to convert data to fit Keras layer_conv_1d?

Tags: r, keras, keras-layer

My looks like this, imported from a CSV. 
The first 10 columns are one variable, columns 11-20 another. 
I want to convert X to the format required by layer_conv_1d, but I can't seem to figure it out. My input shape as I understand it will be input_shape = c(10, 2)

```
 head(X)
             V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10
119584 -0.00376 -0.37296 -0.37115 -0.23247 -0.27340 -0.23744 -0.13158 -0.15616 -0.30983 -0.16377
119585 -0.04429 -0.12537 -0.29646 -0.33452 -0.22150 -0.23713 -0.23534 -0.14301 -0.20708 -0.27785
119586  0.35284  0.18692  0.19451 -0.07150 -0.13848 -0.05159 -0.10095 -0.11955 -0.05895 -0.05839
119587  0.41299  0.54358  0.51501  0.34005  0.12726  0.03750  0.10031  0.03710 -0.01083  0.08740
119588  0.04931  0.31275  0.58071  0.36755  0.30218  0.11168  0.05365  0.10055  0.01358  0.00443
119589  0.00732 -0.01598  0.32237  0.40372  0.31837  0.24941  0.11900  0.03795  0.06665  0.01789
            V11      V12      V13     V14      V15      V16      V17      V18      V19      V20
119584 -0.10191  0.24528  0.22535 0.10682  0.14382  0.10150  0.02138 -0.03733 -0.07256 -0.04263
119585 -0.06495 -0.05586  0.12504 0.15400  0.04311  0.13571  0.07491  0.01583 -0.02098 -0.03453
119586 -0.09273 -0.01665 -0.12912 0.01514  0.04226 -0.01941  0.05849  0.01480 -0.01159 -0.03419
119587  0.07566  0.16196  0.18275 0.06934 -0.02789 -0.01875 -0.11493 -0.00169 -0.00321 -0.03522
119588 -0.09223  0.12027  0.18351 0.24200  0.13347  0.05639 -0.03912 -0.10456 -0.01922 -0.03450
119589 -0.29684 -0.27518 -0.03169 0.07350  0.13735  0.05659 -0.03650 -0.09719 -0.11509 -0.04352
```